# Pine strategy's alert disordered when sending email

Tags: pine-script

When reversing a trade, there are needs to exit a previous trade at first and entry a new trade at second in Pine script. I tried to code it and it performs perfectly when using backtesting. However, regrading on sending email function in TradingView, the email order is inconsistent with Pine script's exit and entry order. Sometimes the sequnces in email box are entry a new trade at first and exit a previous trade at second when using TradingView's sending email function.
Is there have such ordered functions in Pine script to execute closing previous trade and entering a new trade with sending email function so that order is correct with exit first and entry second principles?

My script for creating an alert:

```
if entry_long
    strategy.close("s", alert_message="")
    strategy.entry("l", strategy.long, qty=position_size, alert_message="")
if entry_short
    strategy.close("l", alert_message="")
    strategy.entry("s", strategy.short, qty=position_size, alert_message="")
```

Comment: @PineCoders-LucF

Comment: @PineCoders let see this...